# Relation between edge expansion of graph and sparsity

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I was going through the lectures of [Graph Partitioning and Expanders - Stanford Online](http://theory.stanford.edu/~trevisan/cs359g/). In [lecture 1](http://theory.stanford.edu/~trevisan/cs359g/lecture01.pdf), near the end of page 5, I came across this inequality for regular graphs: $$\phi(S) \leq h(S) \leq 2\cdot \phi(S)$$
where $\phi(S)$ is the [sparsity of graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28graph_theory%29#Sparsest_cut) and $h(S)$ is the [edge expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expander_graph) of the graph.

However, I fail to see how this arises. I think it should be $h(S) \leq \phi(S)$. Is the result given in the lecture notes correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting no response for a long time, I have gone through the lecture once more, and I am pretty confident that the result given in the lecture is incorrect. The sparsity of a regular graph for a given partition is $\phi (S) = \frac{E(S,V-S)}{\frac{d}{|V|}\cdot |S| \cdot |V-S|}$ and the edge expansion of the graph is $h(S) = \frac{E(S,V-S)}{d \cdot min\{|S|,|V-S|\}}$. As for every partition $\{S,V-S\}$, $$|V|\cdot min\{|S|,|V-S|\} \ge  |S|\cdot |V-S| $$
hence,$$\phi (S) \geq h(S)$$Also, because $$2 \cdot max\{|S|,|V-S|\} \geq |V|$$ $$\therefore |V|\cdot min\{|S|,|V-S|\} \le  2\cdot |S|\cdot |V-S|$$
$$\therefore 2\cdot h(S) \geq\phi(S)$$
And, as $h(S)\leq\phi(S)\leq2\cdot h(S)$ for every partition $\{S,V-S\}$, 
$$\therefore h(G) \leq \phi(G) \leq 2\cdot h(G)$$
*PS: However, as the lectures belong to a respectable source, I would still like to hear someone else's opinion on this result.*

Answer (score 0):

The result in the Lecture Notes is indeed incorrect. Your subsequent analysis is valid. Here's [a link](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~satishr/cs270/sp11/rough-notes/Sparse-cuts-spectra.pdf) to Lecture Notes from Berkeley that concur.